# Validation in a WebForms application

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms

I'm working on a WebForms application that consists of a number of pages and each page contains a form which the user fills out. Each form corresponds to a part of an entity meaning that the data from one page/form populates a part of the entity's fields or its child entities' fields.

As an example: a Person's name and birth data is filled out on first page, health status on second page, family information on third page etc. 
The data should of course be valid before continuing to the next page. My customer doesn't want to deal with jQuery or Javascript so this is ruled out. What is "best practice" for implementing validation in this case?

Entity Framework 4 is being used and most of the GUI controls are implemented in HTML and not by WebForms controls.

Comment: well, what about `RequiredFieldValidator` and `RegularExpressionValidator` ?

Comment: But these are WebControls and can't be used for html-elements right?

Comment: you're right, I misread that.

Comment: [This method](http://blog.devshed.nl/2011/01/aspnet-compile-time-supported_06.html) helped a lot with implementing validation in ASP.NET web forms with compile-time support.

Comment: "My customer don't want to deal with jQuery". Hopefully no user will ever have to write javascript. We developers will do this for them. Disallowing any clean-side validation is wicked. Why do they have this requirement?

Comment: @Steven: well he feels that doing everything on the server side is a good thing, client-side calculations are bad. What can I say...

Comment: Client-side validation is fine and makes the UI more responsive and the user more productive. However, you should **ALWAYS** validate on the server as well. Not doing this would be a security bug. That's why the ASP.NET validation controls do both client and server validation for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using custom HTML for your inputs, then you're probably going to have to use some custom code for your validation.  In your server-side form handler you can validate the inputs and render the page back to the user if something was invalid.  The input checking could be as simple as:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FormCollection["someRequiredInput"])
```

You can iterate through all of your inputs, check them according to business logic, and perhaps build a list of errors.  Then after the input checking, if the list of errors isn't empty, render the page back to the user with the errors added to a placeholder of some kind.  If the list is empty, continue processing the form post.

Even if JavaScript wasn't ruled out, you'd still want to perform server-side validation.  *Never* assume that the client-side code worked as intended or was even executed at all.  Client-side validation isn't a security measure, it's just a better user experience.  Server-side validation is the only real validation.

(So you may still be able to add client-side validation for that added UX touch, and if the client does indeed disallow JavaScript then they wouldn't see that and would just use the server-side validation instead.  This is sometimes referred to as "graceful degradation" where you design a web application to still fully function, albeit with slightly less UX goodness, when the user disables client-side technologies.)

Answer (score 2):

> My customer don't want to deal with jQuery och[sic] Javascript so this is ruled out.

Good. Javascript is the **wrong** place to *enforce* validation. Any validation you do with javascript is merely a performance optimization. The *only* acceptable place to truly validate data is on the server.

That out of the way, .Net includes some handy Validation controls you can use. One of those controls is a CustomValidator, that is very easy to override and provide your own server-side code to enforce whatever rules you want. If you're using webforms, these controls are an obvious choice.

Since you have a multi-paged approach, you may also want to look into the Wizard control.